# Как пропатчить live555 под меньший размер rtp?

Tags: linux, streaming, rtsp, rtp

Второй час пытаюсь разобраться в live555. Занизил MTU на устройстве до 1400, но всеравно шлет rtp с размером пакета 1496. Не могу найти в коде где вычитывается буфер в rtp.

Comment: третье письмо темы похоже то что нужно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://lists.live555.com/pipermail/live-devel/2016-April/020062.html

@0andriy направил в нужное направление, а то ctrl+f по исходникам только запутал.

Максимальный размер нагрузки пакета определен константой RTP_PAYLOAD_MAX_SIZE

в файл config.armlinux добавить `-DRTP_PAYLOAD_MAX_SIZE=1300` в
COMPILE_OPTS. Дальше собирается как обычно

Comment: @0andriy и галочку общий поставлю. не ради рейтинга ответ, а чтоб не потерялся

Comment: Можете написать отдельный ответ - этот удалю тогда.

Comment: Не стоит. Вы сами делали половину работы. Так что это совместное творчество :)